# Appointments under capabilities in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't find Appointment under capabilities in the "appxMainfest". I use Visual studio premium 2013.

I want this because I want to add a calendar to my metro application.

Comment: Not in my area of expertise, but this may help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32a56f77-bce9-4c8d-8fb5-95b17d1d0b05/adding-appointment-capability-in-an-uap-ctp6?forum=winappswithcsharp